# EMM Agents not updating Infpormation

Tags: android, ios, iphone, wso2, mdm

I'm running WSO2 EMM and successfully connect iPhone and Android device.

But both of them don't updates info about location, installed apps and battery.

I'm sure the can connect to EMM because i can take some action from EMM console.

I can send message to Android (iPhone messages not working??) I can set passcode lock.

On both I can disable camera. I can Enterprice WIPE on both – I don’t see iphone device wipe?

I miss something or emm don’t work as I expect?

Information are updating only once when I’m enrolling device (all info about location, installed apps, device info, battery, memory) after successfully register no updates.

Is someone running WSO2 EMM with all functionality successfully?

Comment: in the current version of EMM, we only get the location for iOS at the time of enrollment. This is because the location information is retrieved from the agent app. In Android, the location is sent periodically. The server periodically queues messages like Get Device information, Get Application Information and Get Policy Information (if applied) which is then sent to the device when it contacts the server. The location information is retrieved at that time.

Comment: By default, the periodic polling is set to 1 minute (60000 milliseconds) in <DeviceMonitorFrequency> in <EMM_HOME>/repository/conf/emm-config.xml.

Comment: I found solution. I connect to Mysql server and i see that all information are there updated in notifications table. So i found that admin panel is  displaying oldest one. After check few files I found that sql query is wrong and selecting oldest record.
After update everything is updating and showing correct information. 
Update: repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/emm/sqlscripts/db.js
In section var notifications = { change select10 sorting from ASC to DESC
Hope it help someone.

Comment: But i can't force iPhone to receive message...

Comment: Yes, there was an issue with the sql query and there is a public [JIRA](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/EMM-724) created for it.

Comment: In-order to use iOS device, you need to first configure the EMM server as mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM110/iOS+Server+Configurations). Then you need the [MDM APNS certificate](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM110/Generating+a+MDM+APNS+Certificate) which is required to push the message to iOS device.

Comment: Is anyone reading whole topic about issues?
I’m starting to think that nobody understand what I’m writing about in 3 or 4 topics that I have  post here :)
I say that iPhone is register in EMM so I have all necessary certificate and configuration. I can see iPhone location installed app, I can install app from publisher etc. Only send message option from EMM not working and only on iOS device, on android i don’t have such problems.

Comment: Sorry @Awass. I thought no one of the operations were working. The Message operation works using the normal APNs push notification. Just to clarify, did you upload the [App APNs certificate](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM110/Generating+an+APNS+Certificate) to the tenant's iOS Setting page in EMM server?

Comment: Yes i did. I play a little bit with EMM and all working nice. 
Only problem with sending messages to iOS  - I check notification table and there is now records about sending messages so I thing problem is bigger than only APN Cert it’s something with emm  i did’t find out  yet what is it.
I rearrange a little bit EMM so I’m now able to Wipe iOS device and set up Exchange account on it from WEB Console. If anyone  interested let me know I ready to help.

Comment: Hi Nira, Have One questions regarding installing iOS client. After I get enroll url I install root CA and trying to install app. It’s start downloading but can’t install it on iOS device. 
I’m almost sure that it’s something with certificates… Do I need to do something compiling iOS app to install it via web page? Or I need to distribute it over AppStore?

Comment: Hi Awass, I think you have a Apple Developer account. If so, then in-order to install your app, you need add your device to the Devices' list in your apple developer portal by giving your device's UDID and then create the created. Only with Enterprise account can you install apps directly to devices with your organization.

Comment: Can I distribute WSO2 iOS App via AppStore?

Comment: Yes, you can distribute it via the Appstore using your developer account. But you need to modify the Download App page in EMM server to link to your app in the Appstore.

Answer (score 0):

We are conducting a complementary webinar on "Getting your iOS Device Managed by WSO2 Enterprise Mobility Manager on Tuesday, September 23, 2014 at 10 AM PDT. This webinar will cover:

- Overview of WSO2 EMM
- How to create the iOS EMM agent
- Configuring the WSO2 EMM server for iOS
- How to enroll an iOS device to WSO2 EMM
- iOS device management with WSO2 EMM
- Create and monitor policies for iOS devices
- Create your own Enterprise Mobile App Store

For more information and registration , http://wso2.com/library/webinars/2014/09/getting-your-ios-device-managed-by-wso2-enterprise-mobility-manager/